# Optimizing Miller-Rabin Primality Test in Python

Tags: python, performance, primes

I'm writing a Miller-Rabin primality test in Python. While I've briefly looked at how others approached the problem, I decided to try solving the problem on my own. Aside from my choice of language, how could I go about optimizing this code? Any suggestions are welcome and don't hesitate to be brutally honest.

```
def miller_rabin_primality_test(n):

    def mr_check_one(n):
        m = n - 1       
        n = n - 1       
        k =  1          

        while n % 2**k == 0:
            m = n / 2**k      
            k = k + 1         

        return(m)        

    def mr_check_two(n, m, a = [2, 3]):

        for i in range(0, len(a)):
            a = a[i]
            b = pow(a, m, n)
            i = 0

            if(b == n - 1 or b == 1):
                return True

            while(b != n - 1 and i < 7):
                b = pow(b, 2, n)
                i = i + 1

            if(b != n - 1): 
                return False
            else: 
                return True


    m =  mr_check_one(n) 
    r = mr_check_two(n, m)

    return(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

One obvious change to make is that `mr_check_one(n)` does a much more expensive loop than necessary. Here is a much simpler and faster version.

```
def mr_check_one(n):
    m = n - 1

    n = n - 1
    k =  1          
    while n % 2 == 0:  
        k += 1
        n /= 2

    return(m / 2**k)
```

Also, your second function seems really broken. You allegedly loop over `a`, but in your first time through you redefine `a`, reset `i` and return before going through the loop more than once.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the first function. As for the second, I want to check all results of mr_check_one for 2^m mod n AND 3^m mod n (m being the result of mr_check_one). I was trying to loop over again with a different "a" value. Does that make any sense? I wasn't really sure how to go about it. Any ideas?

Comment: I think so, but that means your code is pretty badly broken and thus more appropriate for stackoverflow or similar.

Comment: I rewrote the second function. Hopefully, it's a little better. At a minimum, it is more modular and, perhaps, easier to understand. If you still think it seems pretty badly broken I'll post it over at StackOverflow. Thanks for the insights.